# Next js Server Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function but got: undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to understand why I get the following server error.

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in
> components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
> undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file
> it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

My `_document.js` looks like this:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @next/next/no-document-import-in-page
import React from "react";
// eslint-disable-next-line @next/next/no-document-import-in-page
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";
import { ServerStyleSheets } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="en">
        <Head>
          <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
          <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossOrigin />
          <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Mono:wght@100&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet"
          />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}
// `getInitialProps` belongs to `_document` (instead of `_app`),
// it's compatible with server-side generation (SSG).
MyDocument.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  // Render app and page and get the context of the page with collected side effects.
  const sheets = new ServerStyleSheets();
  const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

  ctx.renderPage = () =>
    originalRenderPage({
      // eslint-disable-next-line react/display-name
      enhanceApp: (App) => (props) => sheets.collect(<App {...props} />),
    });

  const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);

  return {
    ...initialProps,
    // Styles fragment is rendered after the app and page rendering finish.
    styles: [
      ...React.Children.toArray(initialProps.styles),
      sheets.getStyleElement(),
    ],
  };
};
```

the error particularly points to this line:

```
  ctx.renderPage = () =>
    originalRenderPage({
      enhanceApp: (App) => (props) => sheets.collect(<App {...props} />),
    });
```

UDPATE: my `_app.js` file looks like this:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import theme from "../src/theme";

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Remove the server-side injected CSS.
    const jssStyles = document.querySelector("#jss-server-side");
    if (jssStyles) {
      jssStyles.parentElement.removeChild(jssStyles);
    }
  }, []);
  console.log("_app.js", theme);
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        {/* CssBaseline kickstart an elegant, consistent, and simple baseline to build upon. */}
        <CssBaseline />
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

MyApp.propTypes = {
  Component: PropTypes.elementType.isRequired,
  pageProps: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

any ideas of what could be going on?

Comment: I suspect this is not an issue with your `_document` or `_app` files. Are you properly exporting all your pages/components?

Comment: have you found the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line

import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

with

import ThemeProvider from "@material-ui/styles/ThemeProvider";

Answer (score -1):

<App is not imported or defined in the file at all, check it again

Comment: are you saying that I have to import the App from _app.js file?

Comment: @ksusha-beep This is not an issue. `App` is an argument in `(App) => (props) => sheets.collect(<App {...props} />)` and doesn't need to be imported.

Answer (score -1):

There is certain mistakes I noticed:

1. At _document.js

```
ctx.renderPage = () =>
    originalRenderPage({
      // eslint-disable-next-line react/display-name
      enhanceApp: (App) => (props) => sheets.collect(<App {...props} />),
    });
```

Here, the  component is Not Imported, as you can see above.
so, you need to import the App component from where you stored it
to use the Component.

Comment: `App` is an argument in `(App) => (props) => sheets.collect(<App {...props} />)` and doesn't need to be imported. This is not even an issue.